# Store Range of cells into an Array in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to store a range of cells into an array variable in Google Sheets?

Something that will work like this

```
var color = [["red"],["green"],["pink"]];
```

i have tried doing it like this

```
var color = ss.getRange(2,2,3);
```

and printing it out like this

```
ss.getRange(count,2).setValue(color[array_count]);
```

but its not working as i hoped it would be

Comment: Are trying to assign 2D array into one cell? If so, you need to extract the values into string object first

Comment: no its not in my Opening post but the formula with the setValue function is inside a for loop

Comment: ok, I think I understand now. try this: `var color = ss.getRange(2,2,3).getValues();` and also `ss.getRange(count,2).setValue(color[array_count][0]);` under assumption that `array_count` is an index

Comment: thanks its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getRange` is returning a `Range` object. To access its values, you need to call `getValues` function:

```
var color = ss.getRange(2,2,3).getValues();
```

Also, since `color` is a 2D array, and `setValue` is expecting for `string` value, you need to access `color`'s values with `[][]`:

```
ss.getRange(count,2).setValue(color[array_count][0]);
```